# Store strings which have same start, but different end

Tags: algorithms

I need to store a list of strings in some files. In this moment, there are too many strings in too many files, which is a problem for me.

Here is an example of strings:

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaab
aaaaaaac
aaaaaaad
aaaaaaae
aaaaaaam
aaaaaaan
aaaaaaao
aaaaaaap
aaaaaabc
aaaaaabd
aaaaaabe
aaaaaabf
aaaaaabg
....
aaaraaai
aaaraaaj
aaaraaak
aaaraaal
....
acaraaao
acaraaap
acaraaaq
acaraaar
```

As you can see, there is an order, somehow, but is not an order which permits me to play to much.

Some example of what I need based on above example:

```
aaaaaaaa(till e)
aaaaaaam(till p)
aaaaaabc(till g)
```

and so on. But is not that good.

There must a be better way to do that.

I am looking for an algoritm to store the strings in files and those files to have small sizes. If the files are too big, then it will be hard to include them in my application.

Tell me, what's the best way to do what I want ?

**Edit:**

Ideally, I want to store the strings in a json file(s).

The file(s) will be further included in a web application. That's why I want to have a small size for the files. Else, my users should wait too much to download the files.

Of course, if I will store the strings in a file in a better way, then I should parse the content of the file(s) to get the strings back (to be readable). I do prefer this, yes.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm a PHP/JS programmer. But still don't know how can trees help me. I will read the article from wikipedia.

Comment: Those are not just trees, they are tries. They are a sort of data structure used with strings typically.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of *[Write-Only Memory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke))* (or *Storage*)? Will there be queries/read requests for those strings?

Comment: @greybeard No. I'm not familiar with that concept. As of the question if there will be queries/read requests for those strings, I have updated my post. I need to read the strings at some point, but I don't need to query them (to extract some specific strings). I don't care about queries. I just want to store the strings in some files and those files to have a smaller size.

Comment: This may be handled transparently, e.g. [HTTP compression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Comment: @greybeard Not enough. I have already compressed the files and are still too big.

Comment: You show different sources of redundancy: same length strings, considerable common prefixes from one string to the next, sort of *linear progression*. Consider giving a literal, followed by number or strings included and excluded: *aaaaaaaa*5,8,12,4…

Comment: Consider letters as digits in base 26. Each string is an 8-digits number in base 26. Every string is a slighter bigger than the previous one. What we need to do is to compress the small differences between the neighboring pairs, assuming an imaginary 0 as the first string.

Answer (score 1):

How many strings are there in total, and what is the last string in the set?

Assuming these strings are all in lexicographic order and there are no duplicates, what you have is a bunch of 8-digit numbers expressed in base 26.

I'm going to assume that all strings are possible, which means that the set of all possible strings has size $n=26^8$. But there are only $k$ strings stored. The number of possible subsets is, therefore, $n$ choose $k$. And so, assuming the strings are statistically independent, you *need* this many bits to store the set of strings:

$$\log { n \choose k }$$

(All logarithms are base 2 by default; we will use the natural logarithm function $\ln$ in a little bit.)

Note that word, "need". Under these assumptions (which are just assumptions), any representation which uses this many bits is optimal.

A good approximation when $n$ is large (which it is in this case) is to use the [binomial entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function):

$$H(p) = - p \log p - (1-p) \log (1-p)$$

Then:

$$\log { n \choose k } \approx n\,H\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$$

So a very interesting number to know about here is $p = \frac{k}{n}$, which is the probability of a string being in the set.

If $p \approx \frac{1}{2}$, then $H(p) \approx 1$, so $n\,H(p) \approx n$. An optimal representation is to store a bitmap of $n$ entries.

If $p \ll \frac{1}{2}$, then $n\,H(p) \approx k \log n$, and so an optimal representation is to store each of the $k$ strings using $\log n$ bits each.

If $p > \frac{1}{2}$, then it's probably more efficient to store the strings that are *not* in the set.

There is a lot of work on compressing increasing integer sequences; it is a standard workhorse of information retrieval. But what I'm going to suggest for this application is [Elias-Fano coding](https://www.antoniomallia.it/sorted-integers-compression-with-elias-fano-encoding.html), because it's easy to understand.

We will introduce a parameter $b$. Represent each string as a number (convert from base 26), and split each number into the quotient and the remainder when divided by $b$.

We will actually work out $b$ later. For the moment, I will assume $b=4$. We will represent each base-26 numeral $x$ as an integer, and as a pair $(q,r)$ where $q$ is the quotient $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{b} \right\rfloor$, and $r$ is the remainder $x-qb = x \bmod b$.

```
aaaaaaaa = 0 = (0,0)
aaaaaaab = 1 = (0,1)
aaaaaaac = 2 = (0,2)
aaaaaaad = 3 = (0,3)
aaaaaaae = 4 = (1,0)
aaaaaaam = 12 = (3,0)
aaaaaaan = 13 = (3,1)
aaaaaaao = 14 = (3,2)
aaaaaaap = 15 = (3,3)
aaaaaabc = 28 = (7,0)
aaaaaabd = 29 = (7,1)
aaaaaabe = 30 = (7,2)
aaaaaabf = 31 = (7,3)
```

...and so on. We store the remainders as an array:

```
0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
```

We only have to use $\log b$ bits for each entry. In this case, $\log 4 = 2$, so this bit string encodes the remainders:

```
00 01 10 11 00 00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11
```

The compressed size of this array is $k \log b$ bits.

For the quotients, what we will do is count the number of strings that have each quotient. There are 4 strings with quotient 0, 1 string with quotient 1, no strings with quotient 2, 4 strings with quotient 3, and so on. So we can represent this as an array:

```
[4,1,0,4,0,0,0,4]
```

To compress this array, we will use a [unary code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_coding):

```
11110 10 0 11110 0 0 0 11110
```

This unary representation has an interesting structure. The number of `1`s in the compressed representation is exactly equal to $k$, and the number of `0`s in the representation is exactly equal to $\left\lceil \frac{n}{b}\right\rceil$, the maximum possible quotient.

So, ignoring ceilings and floors, the compressed size is the combined size of these two compressed arrays, in bits:

$$k \log b + k + \frac{n}{b}$$

This is minimised when:

$$b = \frac{\ln 2}{p}$$

It is convenient to round $b$ to the next highest power of 2, so that the array for the remainders are stored using a whole number of bits.

And so using this value of $b$, the total size is in bits is:

$$k \log \left( \log (\ln 2) - \log p + 1 + \frac{1}{\ln 2} \right) \approx 2k + k \log \frac{1}{p}$$

You can verify for yourself that this is close to optimal over a large range of $p$.

Comment: Upvoted for Elias-Fano encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most effective first step is to use gaps and consecutive-run-lengths to represent the strings.

Assume all strings are 8-lowercase-letter strings.
Let $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=2$, $\cdots$, $z=25$.
Each string also means a number in base 26, which is also the number of strings that is lexicographically smaller than the string.
Imagine aaaaaaaa as the starting reference string.

The strings in the question will be represented as
$$0, 5,\  \ 7, 4,\  \ 13, 5,\ ..., 4,\ \  ..., 4,\ \ \dots$$
where
$0,5$ means a run of $5$ numbers starting from $0+0=0$, i.e, from aaaaaaaa to aaaaaaae.
$7,4$ means a run of $4$ numbers starting from from $0 + 5 + 7 = 12$, i.e., strings from aaaaaaam to aaaaaaap.
$12, 5$ means a run of $5$ number starting from $12 + 4 + 12 = 1\cdot26+2$, i.e., strings from aaaaaabc to aaaaaabg.
$\cdot, 4$ means $4$ strings from aaaraaai to aaaraaal.
$\cdot, 4$ means $4$ strings from acaraaao to acaraaar.

---

The sequence of numbers obtained above can be compressed by various compression tools such as xz, bzip2 and brotli.

A rough simulation with $p\approx0.355$ produces compression ratio around something like $5497787/961011\approx5.72$, assuming initially each string is stored with 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In [my comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150467/store-strings-which-have-same-start-but-different-end#comment316307_150467), I have suggested to view (*model*) the sequence of strings as an *initial string* and *consecutive runs of increasing strings alternating with gaps*.
Encoding details aside and taking the successor to `aaz` to be `aba`(*number base 26₁₀*), the suggested representation `aaaaaaaa5,8,4,12,5` (4&12 mixed up above) has length 18 for 14 strings of length 8:
5 strings from `aaaaaaaa` to `aaaaaaae`, a gap of 8,
4 strings from `aaaaaaam` to `aaaaaaap`, a gap of 12,
5 strings from `aaaaaabc` to `aaaaaabg`:

I think

> ```
> aaaaaaaa(till e)  
> aaaaaaam(till p)  
> aaaaaabc(till g)
> ```

quite decent, actually.

Not optimal (I think [$n$ choose $k$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/150483/19966) is), but simpler to adapt, say to occasional lexicographically smaller strings: `aaaaaaaa5,8,4,12,5,-13,…` or strings from large alphabets.